# How to calculate $\det(I +A^{50})$ with eigenvalues given

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be a $3 *3$ matrix with the eigenvalues $1,-1,0$. How to calculate $\det(I +A^{50})$ ? I know that the answer is 4, but i have no idea how to approach such a problem

Comment: (i) What are the ev of $A^{50}$? (ii) What are the ev of $I+A^{50}$? (iii) How do you express $\det X$ in terms of the ev of $X$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Since $A$ has three different eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Diagonalizability is not needed. The problem can generally be solved.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: Really? I'm thinking of a real non-diagonalizable $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ whose eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$. What is the determinant of $I+A^{50}$ then?

Comment: The question is: how many are zeros and how many are ones?

Comment: @Mostafa: one zero, one one. Recall that the matrix is *not diagonalizable*, so it will have fewer than three eigenvalues.

Comment: But the multiplicity significantly affects the answer. For example if $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=I+B$ then $$I+A^{50}=2I+50B\implies \det(I+A^{50})=8$$as expected, but $A$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: For the matrix I'm thinking of the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is one, and the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is also one. You are the one who's making a claim that questions such as the OP's can be answered _in general_ knowing only what the eigenvalues are, and that you ghave a method that works for matrices that are not diagonalizable. I notice you still have not applied your claimed method to my example. Shall I conclude you don't in fact have one?

Comment: I'm not the first to imply having only eigenvalues of a matrix can give us such powerful information (in fact Caylay and Hamilton had pointed that out before me :)). I don't say you are wrong. Just saying such a limiting information may not be employed.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda (\lambda ^2-1)$
According to the Cayley Hamilton theorem $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial so $$A^3=A$$

Thus

$$A^{50}=A^{48}A^2=A^{16}A^2=A^{18}=A^2$$

$$\det(I+A^{50})=\det(I+A^2)$$

Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$

$$A=P^{-1}DP\implies A^2=P^{-1}D^2P$$

$$\det(I+A^2)=\det(I+D^2)=1(2)(2)=4$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If we denote the eigenvalues of $A$ by $\lambda$ we have

(1) The eigenvalues of $A^n$ are $\lambda^n$

(2) The eigenvalues of $A+I$ are $1+\lambda$

(3) $\det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots \lambda_n$